# Image.py warning messages

Tags: keras, image

I got the following warning messages when calling the 'model.fit_generator' function on keras:

```
Warning_1: Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:968: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
Warning_2: Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:2685: UserWarning: image file could not be identified because WEBP support not installed
```

What these messages mean and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot information to go on.

One possibility is that you are the old PIL package. You should switch to the newer [Pillow package](https://python-pillow.org/).